# How can I split a string into an array of 2 character blocks in JS?

Tags: javascript, split

For example, when given "hello world", I want `[ "he", "ll", "o ", "wo", "rl", "d" ]` returned.

I've tried `"hello world".split(/../g)`, but it didn't work, I just get empty strings:

```js
console.log("hello world".split(/../g));
```

I've also tried using a capture group which makes me closer to the goal:

```js
console.log("hello world".split(/(..)/g));
```

The only real solution I can think of here is to prune out the empty values with something like this:

```js
let arr = "hello world".split(/(..)/g);

for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i] === "") arr.splice(i, 1);
}

console.log(arr);
```

Even though this *works*, it's a lot to read. Is there a possible way to do this in the split function?

#### Other attempted solutions

```js
let str = "hello world";
let arr = [];
for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    arr.push(str[i++] + (str[i] || ''));
}
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.match()` to split a string into two characters:

```js
var str = 'hello world';
console.log(str.match(/.{1,2}/g));
```

You can also increase the number of splitting by editing `{1,2}` into numbers like `3`, `4`, and `5` as in the example:

3 characters split:

```js
var str = 'hello world';
console.log(str.match(/.{1,3}/g));
```

4 characters split:

```js
var str = 'hello world';
console.log(str.match(/.{1,4}/g));
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This works as expected so I will accept this answer.

Comment: @LoganDevine Glad to help. :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```js
const split = (str = "") => str.match(/.{1,2}/g) || [];
console.log( split("hello world") );
```

Answer (score 1):

It is easier to use a match, but if you must use split you can use your solution with a capture group to keep the text where you split on,  and remove the empty entries afterwards.

The pattern will be `(..?)` to match 2 times any char where the second char is optional using the queation mark.

```js
console.log("hello world".split(/(..?)/).filter(Boolean));
```

Comment: What does `.filter(Boolean)` do? Finds truthy values?

Comment: @LoganDevine Yes, that is correct. You could also do `console.log("hello world".split(/(..?)/).filter(s => s));`